# Click on html element which has specific text in Cucumber

Tags: jquery, html, cucumber, capybara

I have multiple label elements in html like this

```
<label class="article-list">
    first
</label>
<label class="article-list">
    secound
</label>
<label class="article-list">
    Idividual
</label>
```

In scenario I have something like this; "User click "first" option"

Now I need to click on label element which has text "first" in it.  How would I do that?

I know how to get element with class and other stuff but not like this.

Comment: As a side remark, it may be a good idea to use another tag. I see no added value of using `<label>` here...

Comment: Thats structure I got, I can't change it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When finding elements, you can use the `:text` option to specify the text of the element.

To click the "first" label:

```
find('label.article-list', :text => 'first').click
```

To click the "secound" label:

```
find('label.article-list', :text => 'secound').click
```

Of course, the Cucumber step would want to pass the specified text:

```
When /User click "([^"]+)" option/ do |option|
  find('label.article-list', :text => option).click
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`:contains`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) to get the element with given text

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/TN27c/1/)**

```
$('label').click(function(){
   alert(this.className); 
});

$('label:contains(first)').click();
```

**Description**: Select all elements that contain the specified text.

Comment: I can use JQuery in cucumber?

Comment: And(/^User click "([^"]*)" option$/) do |arg|
  $('label:contains(arg)').trigger('click')
end is this good?